# What is the best model for analysing workout time based on the day of the week

Tags: modeling

Suppose If I have a data set of workout times,intensity of the workout,etc for set of individuals.
The patterns repeat based on the day of the week. Suppose Mondays are busy days and people are reluctant to go to a gym/jog, Friday party mode is on and so on.
What is the best model to use in this kind of scenarios.

Suppose I want to model workout time.

Comment: Use day of week as a categorical predictor. We likely can't say more unless you explain in more detail what you want to do.

Comment: I want to measure the effect of the day (Monday,Tuesday..) for the no of hours spent in the gym/jog. This is more like a time series data if I take one individual. But I have a data set of couple of hundred individuals. What I want to know is are there any specific statistical models that can be used in such repetitive tasks.